# How to store several lists and their items

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

The app I'm working on revolves around projects. Each project can contain several lists, and each list is made up of several items.  Each list relates to a single project.

Is it better to have one listitem table structured as such: id, list_id, event_id, content or 2 tables; one containing the relationship between project and list, and the other containing only list items and their relationship to a particular list?

Is it better to have just one table of which each row would be a list item, including that item's relationship to a project and the name of the list it belongs to:

```
list_item(id, project_id, list_name, content, <<other attributes>>)
```

or, have one list item table for all of the list items in the app and and a separate list table:

```
list(id, project_id, name, description, <<other attributes>>)
list_item(id, list_id, content, <<other attributes>>)
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want three tables

1. `PROJECT( project_id, <<other attributes>>)`
2. `LIST( list_id, project_id, <<other attributes (e.g. the name of the list)>> )`
3. `LIST_ITEMS( list_item_id, list_id, <<other attributes>>)`

Combining the `LIST` and `LIST_ITEM` tables wouldn't be appropriate because then you'd be storing attributes of the list (i.e. the list's `name` and `description`) in multiple rows of the `LIST_ITEM` table rather than just once in a single row of the `LIST` table.

Comment: Thank you, correction made. The project table was a given, there are actually many more tables for other functionality but as the question deals specifically with the list aspect I only mentioned those. Why do you suggest to have a table containing the relationship between projects and lists? Is it not more efficient to store the id of the parent project directly in the LIST table? A list can only belong to one project, and a list item can only belong to one list – therefore it is technically possible to use just 1 table. My question is basically why I should NOT do it this way.

Comment: To clarify: list_item( id, project_id, list_name, content )

Comment: @bernk - If each list relates to a single project, then I would get rid of the `project_list` table and add the `project_id` to the `LIST` table.  It seems odd that you wouldn't want to potentially reuse a list across multiple projects though-- it seems like that would force users to do a lot of redundant data entry.